# Need help with template_preprocess_node

Tags: 6, nodes, theming

I have a block with a select box and submit button. The main purpose of the select box is to store a variable in the session. I used template_preprocess_node to filter contents based on user selection.

```
function blackout_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];

  // define a variable to hold your rendered content
  $newContent = "";

  if($_SESSION['myid'] == '1' && $node->field_field1[0]['value'] != '') {
    $newContent = $node->field_field1[0]['view'];
  } else if($_SESSION['myid'] == '2' && $node->field_field2[0]['value'] != '') {
    $newContent = $node->field_field2[0]['view'];
  } else {
    $newContent = $node->body;
  }
  if (strlen($newContent)) $vars['content'] = $newContent;
}
```

Everything is working fine except I have to click submit twice to reload the page contents or I have to move to another page to see re-loaded content. How can I reload content with just one click?

Answer (score 1):

Blocks are rendered in `hook_preprocess_page`. At that time, all implementations of `hook_preprocess_node` have already been executed, so you cannot influence how the node is displayed (apart from messing with the HTML in `$vars['content']`).

If you use Drupal's [Form API](http://drupal.org/node/751826) to implement the select list and the submit button, Drupal will redirect you after submitting the form, so you do not need to reload the page manually. See [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) for why it is generally a good idea to redirect after a HTTP Post.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oswald. You saved my day. Drupal's Form API worked like a charm.